# PC shutting down with hardware failure

Tags: hardware-failure, shutdown

In last 5 month, something weird happening to my PC. By the hardware there is no problem persist. As all hardware installed are working normally, like Fan on CPU, GPU, PSU and no circuit was broken or overheat on some element.

The problem is, when I leave the PC without turn it off/shutdown the PC likely to shutdown by itself if I may call it died. Because is without shutting down process, just off like electricity was cut out.

And when I test to play some Game with high graphic like The Witcher, CoD even FM it happening too, just off.

When I turn it on its back to normal again, I run hardware test using free software no hardware failure or broken. Driver is up to date.

Any idea how to test which hardware causing this issue? as I don't have enough fund to buy new hardware and test it one by one.

Comment: So your computer turns itself off when under stress? sounds like overheating issues.

Comment: Are you sure that problem is not software side? how are you sure about it?

Comment: Yes, its just turn off. Boom off. Thats make me confuse, if its overheat sometimes i used it whole day its not off. Like today already on for almost 20 hr. I leave it for a nap like 3hrs and wake up the PC still on.

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri, Even after fresh OS install the problem still happening. Without any 3rd party software install on machine yet. Test using Win Xp, Win 7 & Win 8 all using 32 & 64 version. So i can assume  software not causing this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably an issue with the PSU.  PSU's typically have circuitry for shutting down under certain conditions (like overload/short).  If your PSU has gone faulty (blown caps are quite common), this could cause a shutdown in the PSU, which may be fixed by powering it back on again.

While it is possible its something else, if it were a CPU or GPU issue you would generally expect the system to throttle down (ie go slower) to dissipate heat rather then shut down.

It could, of-course, be a short occuring on the system causing overvoltage causing a PSU shutdown - although I imagine this is a bit unlikely.

Comment: I've also seen an issue where a particularly 'green' power supply was incompatible with the UPS it was connected to.  When the UPS went on-battery, the computer would turn off.  I suspect the UPS's approximation of a sine wave wasn't close enough.

Comment: "Good" PSUs generally put themselves in a "security" mode where you can't turn on the PC again when there's something like a short-circuit. You've to unplug/plug it back (or use the power switch on the PSU) to shut it down, then you can restart the PC. It seems more like a CPU overheating problem, and the motherboard shutdown itself to prevent damage. (can be a chipset overheating problem too, but it doesn't happen as often as the CPU. Might be GPU too)

Comment: @piernov - Except that the description talks about "no overheat on any elements".  I don't know about this PSU security mode, although certainly you do need to leave some PSU's off for a while to discharge fully if they experience a short or overload condition.

Comment: @davidgo Honestly, i little bit aware with the PSU. But with no real test and no other PSU unit its hard to made decision to buy new PSU unit and installing it. Any method how to troubleshoot this problem except try to change the hardware one by one ?

Comment: I know for the overheating, but it is the most likely to happening. You should run stress-tests like OCCT. You'll have both figures for temperature and voltage. It may help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Let me check the OCCT first.